# Adding item in dictionary showing an error: an item with the same key has already been added. dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I am trying

```
   Dictionary<int, int> list = new Dictionary<int, int>();

   for (int i = 0; i < IDList.Count; i++)
   {
     list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value.ToString()), IDList[i]);
   }
   return list;
```

When I addi a value twice there is no error but the third time it shows the error

> an item with the same key has already been added. dictionary

Someone please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Is this question about Dictionary or  about Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value ?

Comment: Are you sure that `Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value.ToString())` is not retreiving same value ?

Comment: ya it will retrieve same value some time, and some time unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption #1:**

You name your dictionary "list", which suggests, you are not using a dictionary for what it was ment for and should possibly be using a `List<T>` instead.

Dictionary requires that each key (the first parameter to `Add()`) is unique, however `Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"]` looks suspiciously like it is the `Parameters` property of an `SqlCommand` (or one of its parent classes). If so, it will always return the same value in the code you show.

So, if you really want to create a collection of tuples where the first value always is "@ReturnValue" and the second value is `IDList[i]`, then you should use something like `List<Tuple<int, int>>` instead.

Example:

```
  List<Tuple<int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

  for (int i = 0; i < IDList.Count; i++)
  {
    list.Add(
      Tuple.Create(Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value), IDList[i])
    );
  }

  return list;
```

**Assumption #2:**

Actually, the `IDList[i]` values (again, as the name suggests) are the unique values, i.e. your keys, and you simply have the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Add()` parameters the wrong way around.

Comment: When I am trying to use list.Add(
    Tuple.Create(Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value), IDList[i])
  );
I am getting an error No overload for method Add takes 1 argument.

Do i need to add something else, plz give me explanation because I naver used tuple

Comment: You need to use `List<Tuple<int, int>>` as your type as I noted in my answer. I have clarified the example.

Comment: Oh, and please note that the `Tuple` class requires .NET 4.0. But from the error you depict, I think you are using that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try with [Containskey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) and filter before adding.

```
if(!list.ContainsKey(key)
{
    list.Add(value,key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary.Add(…)` takes a `key` and a `value` in that order, and expects the keys to be unique.

Your code will fail if any results from `Cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value` are the same.