# How to compare Dictionary key value and Tuple key value

Tags: c#

I have a List of tuple `<Tuple<int, int>>` x in that I am getting key and value as (45345, 1), (54645,0), (45345,0)
and I have a `Dictionary < int, string > PathList` in that I am getting key and value as (45345, asdfsd234egsgdfgs56345), (54645, 0dfsd234egsgdfgs563456), (45345,0dfsd234egsgdfgs56345234)

I am trying

```
    foreach (var item in PathList)
    {
       if (x.Equals(item.Key) && x[item.Key].Equals(0))
       {
         string path1 = Path.Combine(GetDirectory(item.Value), item.Value);
         File.Delete(path1);
       } 
    }
```

I want to check if X of id is same as PathList of id and x of value must have value 0 then enter inside the condition... what I am doing now in that in any condition I am unable to go inside the If statement.

How to check my condition?

Let me explain more: [check this qus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411746/adding-item-in-dictionary-showing-an-error-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-alread) is this I am returning a list of tuple in which i am getting (54356, 0), (64643, 0), (34365, 1) in in my ascx page I have List of tuple `<Tuple<int, int>>` x, in this x i am getting all return value of list, now in the same ascx page I have `Dictionary < int, string > PathList` in that i am adding the value ImgPathList.Add(54356, 456dfhgdfg6575dfghdf); so I got 2 different list one is x and other is Pathlist.

Now i want to check. if pathlist is having the id and 54356 and x has 54356 and 0 then enter inside the if statement else show the lable msg as file can't be delete

Comment: Can you be clearer: what exactly is `x`? Your use of `x.Equals(item.Key)` and `x[item.Key]` is odd. Also; if you are looping over a dictionary, that usually means something isn't right...

Comment: what is x in your example code?

Comment: if your `x` is a list of `Tuple` then you can't compare `x` with `item.Key` because `item.Key` is an `int`. I'm talking about (`x.Equals(item.Key)`)

Comment: ya x is a list of Tuple, then in this condition what should I do

Comment: I guess first condition of if statement must be: `x.Item1.Equals(item.Key)`

Comment: @Rocky - k; assorted questions: if x is a list, what do you imagine that `x.Equals(item.Key)` means, given that `item.Key` is an integer, and: what do you imagine that `x[item.Key]` is doing, given that `item.Key` is a key, not an index, and then what do you imagine that `{the tuple}.Equals(0)` means? What are you actually trying to **do**? It is very hard to understand what the code is trying to do, simply because none of the tests make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my code as

```
 foreach (var item in PathList)
 {
    Tuple<int, int> temp = new Tuple<int, int>(item.Key, 0);
       //if (x.Equals(item.Key) && x[item.Key].Equals(0))
    if (x.Contains<Tuple<int, int>>(temp))
      {
         string path1 = Path.Combine(GetDirectory(item.Value), item.Value);
         File.Delete(path1);
       }
   }
```

I don't know it is a good way or not but it solved my problem...

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to understand the question, but it sounds like we have, say:

```
var x = Tuple.Create(45345,0);
```

in which case, you just need:

```
string value;
if(PathList.TryGetValue(x.Item1, out value)) {
    // there is an item in the dictionary with key 45345;
    // the value is now in "value"
}
```

There is also something about a zero check; not sure what you meant, but maybe just check `x.Item2`.

If `x` is actually a list, do it in a loop:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    string value;
    if(PathList.TryGetValue(item.Item1, out value)) {
        // there is an element in the dictionary with key matching item;
        // the value is now in "value"
    }
}
```

It *could* be that this is where the zero-check comes in, too:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    string value;
    if(item.Item2 == 0 && PathList.TryGetValue(item.Item1, out value)) {
        // there is an element in the dictionary with key matching item;
        // the value is now in "value"
    }
}
```

However, I can't sufficiently understand the example you give, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Place the breakpoint on the condition, loop until you get to a value that should have entered the if statement, and then see what part of the expression returns false using the "Watch" debug window.

Comment: x.Equals(item.Key) is returns false and x[item.Key].Equals(0) is giving exception x[item.Key].Equals(0) 'x[item.Key]' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' bool

Comment: @Rocky so again: what exactly is `x` ?

Comment: x is a list of Tuple, in which I have id as 34234, 65645, 67567 and with each id I have SP return value as 0 and 1 so it is containing  (34234, 0), (65645, 1)

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are trying to access a member in the List of Tuple by it's key. that is not possible. When you write x[item.key] it returns the element number item.key of X - which does not exist. Instead you can use LINQ such as x.Where(i => i.Item1 == item.key) to find the corresponding tuple.

Comment: Also, x.Equals(item.Key) will always return false, as x is a list, while item.Key is a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpfull: 
In my project i have a dictionary:

```
    public Dictionary<int, double> CpuDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double>();
```

At some point i try to find a key using:

```
            int roundedcpupercentage = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round(cpuusagepercentage));
            if (CpuDictionary.ContainsKey(roundedcpupercentage))
            {
                temp.CPU = CpuDictionary[roundedcpupercentage];
                temp.Watt = temp.CPU;
            }
```

The containskey function is working perfectly for me. Maybe you should try something similar.

Answer (score 0):

That's it if you want to check if there's a tuple with the dictionary's key as `Item1` and `Item2==0`:

```
foreach(var item in pathList) { 
    var xItem = x.Find(i => i.Item1 == item.Key && i.Item2 == 0);
    if(xItem =! null) { 
        // YourTuple.Item1==item.Key && YourTuple.Item2==0 => true
    }
}
```

Note: in your example above you have two identical dictionary keys.

Comment: Looping over a dictionary, and then finding each key using `Find` on a list is a really inefficient way of doing this; that is `O(N*M)`. Contrast looping on the list (`O(N)`) and using the dictionary to lookup (`O(1)`) - which is therefore `O(N)`.

Comment: This is true enough. But it's not clear from the question what the OP actually is trying to do, so i couldn't anticipate how to improve his approach. Hence i've just taken the questions's title as requirement.

Comment: Yes, the context here is painfully confusing - agreed.